# Spark - S3 - Access & Secret Key configured in code, is overridden with IAM Role

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am working on creating Spark job in Java which explicitly specifies IAM user with access & secret key in runtime. It can read or write to S3 with no issue in local machine using the keys. However, when I promote the job to Cloudera Oozie, it keeps picking up IAM role attached to EC2 instance (which can only read certain S3 slices). The goal is to set a IAM user per tenant who can only access own slice in S3 under the same bucket (multi tenancy). Can anyone advise me if you know how to prevent IAM role from overriding IAM user credentials in Spark? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?